# Randomize array of Strings, but without repeating elements

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'd like to ask how should I implement a method in Java that takes all the elements from an array and shuffle them. Think like a deck of playing cards.

This is my try:

```
// a is an array of type String
public void randomize()
{
    for(int i=0; i<k; ++i)
    {
        int idx = new Random().nextInt(k);
        String random = (a[idx]);
        System.out.println(random);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to write it from scratch?

Comment: see http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/ for a discussion of shuffling algorithms

Comment: I'd like to know an idea or the methon explained. :)

Comment: This was answered here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array

Comment: @Alnitak it is not completely a duplicate: in the other question it is an array of primitives whereas here it is an array of objects. In particular the short and sweet `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(a));` does not work with an `int[]` but does work with a `String[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Collections.shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-)(). First convert your array to a List

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I gave your +1!

Comment: Glad it worked. You might accept it as the correct answer as well.

Comment: Yes. It is the correct answer. I don't know why a guy flagged my question... before asking it I saw the other questions and none of the answers worked. However thank you so much. I learned smth new today. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using built-in methods is probably the easiest and cleanest solution:

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(a)); //shuffles the original array too
```

This works because the [`asList` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) (emphasis mine):

> Returns a fixed-size list *backed by the specified array*. (***Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array***.)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I gave your +1!

Answer (score 0):

You mean somethin like this one? Or you are looking for something more complex?

```
static void shuffleArray(String[] ar)
  {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
      // Simple swap
      int a = ar[index];
      ar[index] = ar[i];
      ar[i] = a;
    }
  }
```